# Factor analysis across different levels of data aggregation

Tags: pca, data-transformation, factor-analysis

I have survey data for thousands of individuals from hundreds of towns. I want to identify factors underlying certain characteristics at the town level and the individual level. The individual level is straightforward. But I'm less clear on how to proceed with the town-level data.

I am considering two approaches.

1) We can calculate community-level averages for each covariate and then calculate loadings on those averages. (The downside is that averaging up front before calculating loadings would lose a lot of information.)

2) we can calculate loadings on the individual-level data and then calculate the factors using community-level averages of the covariates. (i.e., $\text{factors} = \text{loadings} * \text{comm_level_avgs}$.) I'm leaning toward this option, but **I'm not sure if we can calculate loadings at one level of aggregation (individual data) and then use them to calculate factors at a different level of aggregation (town-level averages).**

Any thoughts are appreciated! Use option 1, 2, neither?

**Based on ttnphns comment, I've added an example on how I'm running the analysis here.**

I haven't uploaded simulation data because the data aren't really the point. I care about whether my suggestions are based on sound statistical reasoning.

Below is the code I use to calculate individual-level loadings, with some code that demonstrates the two different options I'm considering for calculating town-level factors.

```
###   What I've done so far
 require(psych)
#  Factor Analysis
### Define the correlation matrix of all X variables (all model inputs)
corMat <- cor(variables)
#display the correlation matrix
corMat


 #use fa() to conduct an oblique principal-axis exploratory factor analysis
 #save the individual-level data solution to an R variable, 
 n = 2
 ind_level_solution <- fa(r = corMat, nfactors = n, rotate = "oblimin", fm = "pa")
 #display the solution output
 ind_level_solution

###   What I need to make a decision about
# Define a new matrix (call it town_matrix) where each observation is a town,    
# with covariates defined as town-level covariate averages
   town_matrix = aggregate(variables, by = town_ID, mean)

# Option 1: Run 
    town_mean_solution = fa(town_matrix, ...)
    town_factors1 = (town_mean_solution %*% town_matrix)

# Option 2: Like above, run 
     ind_level_solution = fa(corMat, ...) 
#  but then calculate factors with 
     town_factors2 = (ind_level_solution %*% town_matrix)
```

Comment: I feel the question isn't clear enough. Please show how you do both your calculations with a concrete example.

Comment: @ttnphns +1, thanks for considering it. I'll put together an example in a few hours.

Comment: Sorry, I hardly understand the code because I'm not R user; I expected you to give also data and numbers for a reader to be able to reproduce it by a familiar software. For example, it is totally unclear to me whether ind_level_solution is loadings or eigenvectors or something else and whether it has 2 columns or 2 rows. Etc.

Comment: P.S. I was trying to run your code on an online R resource http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/Rweb/ but it didn't process it. Maybe because the resourse has no psych package installed. If you are familiar with a better online resourse or how to bypass the problem I'd be very thankful. I do need occasionally to run R code, still I don't want to instal it on my pc.

Comment: @ttnphns I appreciate you trying! I do not know of an online R resource.  I'm traveling a bit today, so I'll sit down and see what I can do with simulation data tomorrow. In the meantime, my fundamental question might be answerable without data. **Can you calculate loadings at one level of aggregation (e.g., individual-level) and then use those loadings to calculate factors at a different level of aggregation (e.g., town-level)?**

Comment: Speaking most _generally_, you may obtain loadings on one data and then use it to compute factor scores in a completely different data. If you reason that those "new" or "another" data come from a population with the same factor structure. And those data might have another number of cases than the initial one had. Please be aware that I'm saying nothing about your specific code since I can't check it.